Angular 18 Missing "./compat/firestore/" specifier in "@angular/fire" package
I recently upgraded my Angular project from version 13 to 18, but I'm encountering an issue when running ng serve. The error message states: 'Missing "./compat/firestore/" specifier in "@angular/fire" package'. Below is my package.json for reference.


`{
  "name": "social-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^18.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^18.2.14",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^18.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "^18.2.13",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^16.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^16.0.0",
    "firebase": "^11.0.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^13.27.0",
    "howler": "^2.2.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "sharp": "^0.29.3",
    "stripe": "^8.195.0",
    "swiper": "^7.4.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1802.12",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.13",
    "@angular/localize": "^18.2.13",
    "@capacitor/cli": "latest",
    "@types/howler": "^2.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/sharp": "^0.29.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "sass": "^1.81.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5"
  }
}`



I tried uninstalling and reinstalling @angular/fire, but the issue persists.
